# SwiftUI Picker to change second state var in the same View

Tags: binding, swiftui, state

I am missing something in my understanding of SwiftUI State variables.

I have a Picker and I want to apply the value from the Picker to another State var.

Specifically I want to use a Picker to spect a MassUnit and apply the new MassUnit to a Measurement.  When the MassUnit is selected, the measurement uses .convert or .converted to change the Measurement to the new unit.

If you look at the code below, the value of converted is correctly calculated but I can’t set max to the new value and I can't use max.convert to change it.

What am I doing wrong?  (I've tried applying a Binding var but that wasn't working.  My understanding is that this view should be able to mutate this state property.)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConverterView: View
{
    @State var massUnit: UnitMass = .pounds
    @State var min: Measurement<UnitMass> = Measurement(value: 1, unit: .pounds)
    @State var max: Measurement<UnitMass> = Measurement(value: 1.5, unit: .pounds)
    
    private let massFormatter = MewsMassFormatter()
    private let unitFormatter = MewsMassFormatter(style: .long)

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker(selection: $massUnit,
                   label: Text("Weight Units"),
                   content: {
                        ForEach(massUnits, id: \.symbol) {
                            Text(unitFormatter.string(from: $0)).tag($0)
                        }
                   })
                .onChange(of: $massUnit.wrappedValue, perform: { newMassUnit in
                    let converted = $max.wrappedValue.converted(to: newMassUnit)
                    $max.wrappedValue = converted //doesn't work
                    $max.wrappedValue.value = converted.value //doesn't work
    //              $max.wrappedValue.unit = converted.unit //doesn't compile
                    $max.wrappedValue.convert(to: newMassUnit) //doesn't work
                })

            TextField("Min", value: $min, formatter: massFormatter).keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            TextField("Max", value: $max, formatter: massFormatter).keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            Text(unitFormatter.string(from: $massUnit.wrappedValue))
        }
    }
}

struct ConverterView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ConverterView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because The question was based on a faulty premise.  The real problem lay outside the scope of the code as presented.

Answer (score 1):

No need `$` sign and wrapped value. you can directly assign.

```
.onChange(of: massUnit, perform: { newMassUnit in
                    let converted = max.converted(to: newMassUnit)
                    max = converted
                    max.convert(to: newMassUnit)
})
```

And,

```
Text(unitFormatter.string(from: massUnit))
```